# Outputting a .txt file from a .csv file

Tags: ruby, csv

I wrote this little script in PHP a bit ago. It takes a .csv file and outputs a .txt file with certain data arranged in a "psuedo-array" looking format. I recently started messing around with Ruby so I decided to redo it. It wound up essentially as an exact translation, though.

Is there a simpler / more Ruby way to do this?

```
require "csv"

class ArrayGenerator

    def initialize( file )
        @file = file
        open_csv
    end

    private
    def open_csv
        File.open("#{@file}" + "_output.txt", 'w') do |file|
            CSV.foreach(@file) do |row|
                lat = row[6]
                lon = row[7]
                img = "#{row[0]}".downcase
                part = "#{row[2]}"
                loc = "#{row[5]}"
                country = "#{row[4]}"
                focus =  "#{row[3]}"
                desc = "#{row[8]}"
                link = "#{row[9]}"

                file.write("[#{lat}, #{lon}, #{img}, #{part}, #{loc}, #{focus}, #{country}, #{desc}, #{link}],
")
            end
        end
    end
end

ARGV.each do |file|
    g = ArrayGenerator.new( file )
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
img = "#{row[0]}".downcase
part = "#{row[2]}"
loc = "#{row[5]}"
country = "#{row[4]}"
focus =  "#{row[3]}"
desc = "#{row[8]}"
link = "#{row[9]}"
```

The only difference between writing `"#{ expression }"` (without anything else in the string) and just writing `expression` is that the former converts the result of the expression to a string. If that is your intent, you should write `expression.to_s` instead because that way it's clearer what's going on.

However in your case the values in `row` are already string, so there's no need to convert them to strings, so using `"#{}"` here is just redundant. You can just write `img = row[0].downcase`, `part = row[2]` etc.

Instead of taking each column out of the `row` array individually, you can also write this:

```
CSV.foreach(@file) do |img, _, part, focus, country, loc, lat, lon, desc, link|
  img = img.downcase
  file.puts("[#{lat}, #{lon}, #{img}, #{part}, #{loc}, #{focus}, #{country}, #{desc}, #{link}],")
end
```

Note that I've used the variable name `_` to denote a variable we're not going to use because you never used `row[1]` in your code (`_` is conventionally used in Ruby to denote variables that aren't used and is in fact the only variable name that's allowed to appear multiple times in a parameter list).

I've also replaced `write` with `puts` which automatically inserts a newline after the string, so you don't have to include the newline in the string.

---

A couple of more general design notes:

I think `open_csv` is rather misleadingly named. It does a lot more than just opening the csv file.

I also think it's a bad idea to call `open_csv` in your constructor. Generally the constructor should only set up the object, so that it's in a usable state. It should not do any actual work. The way you designed it, everything the object is ever going to do is done in the constructor. That's why when you use it, you create the object with `ArrayGenerator.new` and then never do anything with the object - because everything that can be done with the object has already been in the constructor. Another sign of this is that the only public method in your class is `initialize`. This is a very strange way to use objects.

On a related note there's no point in creating a `g` variable if you're not going to use it.

You should either redesign your class to behave more like an actual class, with a usage more like this:

```
g = ArrayGenerator.new( file )
g.generate
```

Or you could get rid of your class altogether and instead define a stand-alone method that could be used like this:

```
generate_array( file )
```